# How to print two values from a list next to each other and then find the minimum values from the printed values

Tags: r, list

I have a list of sets of data in R. From these lists, I am trying to extract specific values for future use.

I want to be able to do two things (if it is possible).

1. I want to be able to print the name of the dataset from the list next to a value I've calculated and extracted from list.
2. I want to be able to find the minimum value from that printed data and it's corresponding data name.

Here is some code that is similar to what I am using already and I will try to make a reproducible example:

```
#creating data
pressure <- runif(30, min = 3750, max = 4500)
value <- runif(30, min = 0, max = 100)
stage <- rep(c(1, 2, 3), each = 10)
raw.data <- data.frame(pressure, value, stage)


#creating my list
test_results <- purrr::pmap(data.frame(Press.Well = seq(3750, 4500, 50)),
                       ~ dplyr::filter(raw.data, pressure > ..1)) %>%
  purrr::map(. %>%
               group_by(stage) %>%
               summarize(
                 difference = (max(value) - min(value)) )
             ) %>%
  setNames(seq(3750, 4500, 50))


#made a function to view what I want to from each of the lists
print_mean <- function(list) {
  
  for (item in 1:length(list)) {    
    print(mean(test_results[[item]]$difference, na.rm = T))
  }

}

print_mean(test_results)
```

So going back to what I am looking for:

1 - I want to be able to print out something like the following from the lists:

| Set Name in this column | Mean value in this column |
| --- | --- |
| 3750 | ### |
| 3800 | ### |
| ... | ### |
| 4500 | ### |

I know I can get the names of the sets by using `names(test_results)` and the list of values I'm interested in by using the function I created, `print_mean(test_results)`, but I don't know how to put them together.

And 2 - I would like to pull out the smallest mean value from the table above and it's corresponding set name, e.g. `3900 12.8` (or whatever the min value might be). But I am not sure how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to bind the `list` elements together (`bind_rows`) and then do a group by `mean`

```
library(dplyr)
out <- bind_rows(test_results, .id = 'Name') %>% 
    group_by(Name) %>% 
    summarise(Mean_diff = mean(difference, na.rm = TRUE))
```

-output

```
out
# A tibble: 15 × 2
   Name  Mean_diff
   <chr>     <dbl>
 1 3750      77.2 
 2 3800      77.2 
 3 3850      77.0 
 4 3900      62.7 
 5 3950      62.7 
 6 4000      62.7 
 7 4050      62.7 
 8 4100      62.7 
 9 4150      58.0 
10 4200      56.4 
11 4250      43.2 
12 4300      43.2 
13 4350       6.86
14 4400       0   
15 4450       0
```

Then to extract the row with `min` value of `mean`

```
out %>%
  slice_min(n = 1, order_by = Mean_diff)
```

---

Or if we want to use `base R` - loop over the `list` with `lapply`, extract the 'difference' column, get the `mean` and `stack` the named `vector` to a two column data.frame

```
stack(lapply(test_results, \(x) mean(x$difference, na.rm = TRUE)))[2:1]
```

NOTE: The OP didn't use `set.seed`, so the values will be different from the expected output